# Evaluating boolean value of a variable in XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="addUDF" select="myUtils:MyFunction()"/>  
 <xsl:if test="$addUDF='true'">
  <xsl:text>Anything</xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
```

Myfunction is an extension function that returns boolean value viz true/false

In debugging mode when addUDF has been returned true if condition evalutes to true and yet xsl:text line won't get executed. The statement within if condition simply gets skipped.

Comment: If the calling function passes a true Boolean, either change your condition to `test="$addUDF = true()"` or even better `test="$addUDF"`.

Comment: The string `'true'` will always be converted to `true()` anyway, since it's non-empty, but you might have type conversion errors if using XPath 2.0. See if you are getting error messages.

Comment: How is myUtils:MyFunction declared?  Is it returning an xs:boolean value, or the strings 'true' or 'false'?